# Exporting Decomposed Data from R into Excel

Tags: r, data-export

I am trying to export decomposed data the decomposed time series data from R into excel. Can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Maybe try : `result <- do.call(cbind, A.modwt)` and then you can write it to csv with `write.csv(result, 'result.csv')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ronak Shah. It does work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
bind_cols(A.modwt) %>%
      write_csv(result, 'result.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer was given by @Ronak Shah works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the data with `do.call`

```
result <- do.call(cbind, A.modwt)
```

and then use `write.csv` to write the data.

```
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Well noted!